# Display JFrame inside JPanel in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Is this possible to add a JFrame into a JPanel in Java.
i m using a java program which is giving output as a frame which i wanted to display inside another program's JPanel on click of a button.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about `JInternalFrame`. I think it's the way to go here.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

Answer (score 2):

You could call `getContentPane()` on the JFrame to extract its main contents as a JPanel (usually) and without the menu bar and decorations, and display that as a JPanel though best would probably be to update the original program so that it produces a JPanel and not a JFrame.